# Spring web app error

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

This run-time error occurs in my spring mvc project. The target server apache tomcat 8.0. could you help me to solve this problem :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [31] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\mehrdad\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\CPNC\org\apache\jsp\pages\home_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

An error occurred at line: [42] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\mehrdad\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\CPNC\org\apache\jsp\pages\home_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
```

this is home.jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Home page</h1>
<p>This is Home page. It's available for all users.<br/>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sec/moderation.html">Moderation page</a><br/>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/first.html">First Admin page</a><br/>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/second.html">Second Admin page</a><br/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be a problem with multiple (conflicting) servlet api jars in the class path. Check your lib directory once and make sure that you are using 3+ api version.

Comment: Can you list jar files inside your war?

Comment: this image shows my jar files: http://8pic.ir/images/uo6ua85eszihkrgx315x.jpg

Comment: In general, it's better to use the <c:url... /> JSTL tag than manually pre-pending the context root. No clue on the error except the already suggested one, though.

Comment: @MehrdadAbdolghafari It would be better to list the dependencies as text in the question itself. Might be useful for people reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove libraries `javax.servlet-api`, `servlet-api`, `jsp-api`, `jstl` from the resulting WAR file. Those libraries should be used at compile time but they should not be included in a WAR archive. The server (eg. Tomcat) that compiles JSP files supplies those dependencies. Your libraries takes precedence over server supplied ones and that causes the error.

If you are using Maven or Gradle set the scope of the dependency to `provided` value.